# MongoDB: I can't seem to query matches with findOne (using mongoose,mLab)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

```
async function red(ctx) {
  let redurl = "//url here";
  url.findOne({ shortenedLink: redurl }, (err, data) => {
    //find if short url matches long url in db
    if (err) throw err;
    if (data) {
      //if matches then redirect to long url
      ctx.redirect(data.url);
      console.log("matched");
    } else console.error("--"); //getting this error, it doesn't find any matches even though there are
  });
}
```

Im using koa.js for this. Even though there are matches it cant seem to match.

I connect to mLab with mongoose.connect

```
const url = require('./models/url'); //require model
```

This is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const urlSchema = new Schema({
  url: String,
  shortenedLink: String
},{timestamps: true});

const url = mongoose.model('url',urlSchema);
module.exports = url;
```

the full code is [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ee).

Comment: What does `findOne` return? Any error or something?

Comment: The error I set if it finds no matches returns. And I know for a fact that there are actually matches.

Comment: Are you querying an existing collection? If so, what is the name of that collection? Mongoose will query a collection called `urls` (plural) with the code you're showing.

Comment: Yes I'm querying an existing collection . The full code can be found [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ee)

Comment: The name of the collection I set in schema is 'url' in mLab its called `urls`  _in plural_

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.find()` instead of `.findOne()`? I've done this project as well, though I used promises (you can set up mongoose to use them globally):

```
//search for shortened URL ID in database, then redirect user if shortened URL ID is found
//if not found, send JSON response with error

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Urls.find({
        shortlink: req.params.id
    }).then((url) => {
        let redirecturl = url[0].url;
        res.redirect(redirecturl);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(404).send({error: 'Shortened URL ID not found'});
    });
});
```